# Finding the magnitude of the transfer function

Tags: transistors, ac, drawing

This is the circuit, where some of the components values where given; the others I found myself. (Sorry I have no link to the design, I needed membership there)

[image]

The following part says to draw the corresponding AC-circuit and find the magnitude of the transfer function U2/U1 at ω = 0, ω = infinite, and ω = 1/sqrt(LC)

This is the AC drawing that I have done:

[image]

[image: g]

I am asking this question for the purpose of getting some feedback about the way I solved this problem, and because I'm not sure if it’s done correctly.

By no means this is homework. I am just trying to learn transistors and not knowing what the correct answer is causes doubts about whether I did it right or not.

Comment: How can the transfer function be unity? You haven’t explained why.

Comment: the transfer function was given, saying that is approx to 1 so we just use it as one

Comment: Then why is R2 down at 100 ohms. If it were more like 10 kohm I’d agree with you.

Comment: @Andyaka It's probably because the problem creators want those solving the problem to assume that the base is biased for the load.

Comment: @Andy aka, actually Urb = 7,3V and Ib= 20μ so Rb= Urb/Ib

Comment: Eh? That is total nonsense at one extreme or total irrelevance at the other extreme. Half way between those extremes it’s inexplicable. Just think about what you have said @be1995 and put yourself in my position in trying to decode the mumbo jumbo you said.

Comment: @Andy aka, sorry here I uploaded a picture of my answer for that part on the top left corner you can see the given elements [Link to a pic of my solution](https://imgur.com/Fc5QqY5)

Comment: @Andy aka, did you have the change to look at the photo above ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyzsPw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$

Using KCL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{y}=\text{I}_\text{c}+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{t}=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_6+\text{I}_\text{y}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\text{I}_\text{t}+\text{I}_\text{c}\\
\\
\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{c}}{\text{I}_\text{t}}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{x}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{y}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{V}_4-\text{V}_1=\alpha
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, you can solve your problem using:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Iy == Ic + I4, It == I3 + I4, Ix == I2 + I3, I8 == I5 + I7, 
   I7 == I6 + Iy, I1 == I5 + I6, Ix == I1 + I2, \[Beta] == Ic/It, 
   I8 == It + Ic, Ix == (Vx - V5)/R1, I2 == (V5)/R2, 
   I3 == (V5 - V4)/R3, I4 == (Vy - V4)/R4, I5 == (V1)/R5, 
   I7 == (V1 - V2)/R6, I7 == V2/R7, V4 - V1 == \[Alpha]}, {Ix, I2, I3,
    It, I1, I4, Ic, I8, I5, I7, I6, Iy, V5, V4, V3, V1, V2}]]
```

---

**EDIT**

Let's assume \$\alpha=\frac{7}{10}\$, \$\beta=100\$ and \$\text{V}_\text{x}=10\$. In the (complex) s-domain we need to solve the following system of equations (I used Mathematica 12.0 to solve it):

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Iy == Ic + I4, It == I3 + I4, Ix == I2 + I3, I8 == I5 + I7, 
   I7 == I6 + Iy, I1 == I5 + I6, Ix == I1 + I2, I8 == It + Ic, 
   100 == Ic/It, Ix == ((10/s) - V5)/600, 
   I2 == V5/(((((s*20*10^(-6)))*((1/(s*2*10^(-9)))))/(((1/(s*2*10^(-9)\
))) + ((s*20*10^(-6)))))), I3 == (V5 - V4)/(1/(s*1*10^(-9))), 
   I4 == ((18/s) - V4)/100, I5 == V1/2000, 
   I7 == (V1 - V2)/((1/(s*100*10^(-9)))), I7 == V2/100, 
   V4 - V1 == (7/10)/s}, {V1, V2, V4, V5, Ic, It, Ix, Iy, I1, I2, I3, 
   I4, I5, I6, I7, I8}]]
```

Now, I used inverse Laplace transform to plot the voltage \$\text{V}_2\left(t\right)\$:

[image]

Where:

- $$\lim_{t\to0}\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=-\frac{7}{10}\tag5$$
- $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{V}_2\left(t\right)=0\tag6$$

The maximum occurs when \$t\approx1.20098\space\mu\text{s}\$ and is then equal to:

$$\hat{\text{V}}_2\left(1.20098\right)\approx16.6022\space\text{V}\tag7$$

Comment: if I may ask why the circuit is different? when I said I had to find the components for Dc. I just had to find what Ib using your formula from above and R2. My problem is that I don't know if the AC  drawing is good and the magnitude. If you could help me with that I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: can you please have a look at the comment above. I would really appreciate it

Comment: @be1995 I do not understand your question

Comment: @JanEerland They asked for small signal gain.